# Increasing horizontal space between chapter number and chapter title in scrreprt

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

I would like to change the distance between the chapter number and the chapter text. A poor way to do it would be renew `\thechapter`, but this affects section titles too. Other answers seem to suggest modifying the `.cls` file via `etoolbox` or `\renewcommand`, but it seems that `\renewcommand\thesection...` would actually be more readable and simpler for debugging. What is the 'natural' way to do this?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\ \ }

\begin{document}
 \chapter{Blah}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the value (here 4 cm) to your needs.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot
  \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\hspace{4cm}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Canh chua}
\end{document}
```

---

This may seem complicated, and we can just as well make this more simple and still see the very same result.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\hspace{4cm}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Canh chua}
\end{document}
```

Later, you decide to use the KOMA feature of a prefix line, to make the appearance match with the standard classes and add `chapterprefix`. You also decide to have an appenddix, knowing that KOMA-script will now set the dot at the end of the numbers to match the definitions of the german *Duden*.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\hspace{4cm}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Canh chua}
\appendix
\chapter{Pho King Crazy}
\end{document}
```

What we get is this:

[image: phoKingCrazy]

Now, where is all the stuff gone? The word appendix, that would have printed in the babel language at use. Where is the dot?
We deleted it. Simple as that.
The original defenition uses conditionals to deal with the various options KOMA provides. If we want to change the space, let's just change the space and nothing more.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
      \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot
        \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\hspace{4cm}}}%
    }
\begin{document}
\chapter{Canh chua}
\appendix
\chapter{Pho King Crazy}
\end{document}
```

[image: phoKinCrazyExtended]

Comment: If you want to achieve centered chapter headings, there is another way.

Comment: Brute force? Is there no special KOMA related command for this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is the documented interface. Usually, there is an `\enspace`. Of course, Markus could also define a `\chapnumtitlesep`, instead of enspace. The rest is conditional stuff, in case you change global options. For example, if you want to have *Chapter number* on its own line, like in the standard classes, the above changed space will never apply.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See edit

Comment: Ah yes. Very elaborate... Unfortunately I can't upvote again ;-)